# How to concatenate similar tags in a XML file

Tags: php, mysql, xml

There can be one or many similar XML tags inside a single XML record set. If there are many, I need them to be in a one tag, comma separated. 
This is the XML I have now.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Results>
        <Recordset setCount="3">

            <Record setEntry="0">
                <AU>One</AU>
                <AU>Two</AU>
                <AU>three</AU>
            </Record>

            <Record setEntry="1">
                <AU>One</AU>
                <AU>Two</AU>
                <AU>Three</AU>
                <AU>Four</AU>
                <AU>Five</AU>
                <AU>Six</AU>
                <AU>Seven</AU>
            </Record>

            <Record setEntry="2">
                <AU>One</AU>
            </Record>

        </Recordset>
    </Results>
```

I need it to be like this. Please help with a code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Results>
<Recordset setCount="3">

<Record setEntry="0">
<AU>One, Two, Three</AU>
</Record>

<Record setEntry="1">
<AU>One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven</AU>
</Record>

<Record setEntry="2">
<AU>One</AU>
</Record>

</Recordset>
</Results>
```

Comment: Before asking for code to be written for you, please make an attempt at solving the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with xpath. Here is an example with *Simplexml*:

You can first find all the first leafs:

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//*[not(*) and not(preceding-sibling::*)]') as $firstLeaf) {
    ...
}
```

and then you concat the text together with all the following leafs:

```
    $followingWithSameName = 'following-sibling::*[name(.) = name(preceding-sibling::*[last()])]';
    // change the text of the first leaf
    $firstLeaf[0] = implode(', ', $firstLeaf->xpath(".|$followingWithSameName"));
```

and then you remove all the following leafs:

```
    // remove all following leafs with the same name
    foreach ($firstLeaf->xpath($followingWithSameName) as $leaf) {
        unset($leaf[0]);
    }
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/private/7ab2f85b88d63e)

Comment: Please see this "[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26542442/how-to-concatenate-similar-tags-in-a-xml)" @hakre