# How to concatenate similar tags in a XML

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Please help me with coding. @hakre

I have the following XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <Results>
    <Recordset setCount="3">

      <Record setEntry="0">
        <TI>Test-1</TI>
        <MO>Mo-1</MO>
        <AU>One</AU>
        <AU>Two</AU>
        <AU>three</AU>
        <JF>OK</JF>
        <JT />
      </Record>

      <Record setEntry="1">
        <TI>Test-2</TI>
        <MO>Mo-2</MO>
        <AU>One</AU>
        <AU>Two</AU>
        <AU>Three</AU>
        <AU>Four</AU>
        <AU>Five</AU>
        <AU>Six</AU>
        <AU>Seven</AU>
        <JF />
        <JT />
      </Record>

      <Record setEntry="2">
        <TI>Test31</TI>
        <MO>Mo-3</MO>
        <AU>One</AU>
        <AU />
        <JF />
        <JT />
      </Record>

    </Recordset>
  </Results>
```

I want it to be like the following XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <Results>
    <Recordset setCount="3">

      <Record setEntry="0">
        <TI>Test-1</TI>
        <MO>Mo-1</MO>
        <AU>One; Two; Tree</AU>
        <JF>OK</JF>
        <JT />
      </Record>

      <Record setEntry="1">
        <TI>Test-2</TI>
        <MO>Mo-2</MO>
        <AU>One; Two; Three; Four; Five; Six; Seven</AU>
        <JF />
        <JT />
      </Record>

      <Record setEntry="2">
        <TI>Test31</TI>
        <MO>Mo-3</MO>
        <AU>One</AU>
        <JF />
        <JT />
      </Record>

    </Recordset>
  </Results>
```

These are the things I need to get done.

1. Concatenate values in SIMILAR XML tags into a one tag, separated by ";". ("AU tags" in the given example)
2. Leave the blank XML tags as they are.
3. PHP to create and save the second XML file by the name "SECOND.XML".

Comment: <?php $xml = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0"?> {XML} foreach ($xml->xpath('//*[not() and not(preceding-sibling::)]') as $firstLeaf) { $followingWithSameName = 'following-sibling::*[name(.) = name(preceding-sibling::*[last()])]'; // change the text of the first leaf $firstLeaf[0] = implode(', ', $firstLeaf->xpath(".|$followingWithSameName")); // remove all following leafs with the same name foreach ($firstLeaf->xpath($followingWithSameName) as $leaf) { unset($leaf[0]); } } echo $xml->asXML();

Comment: @Sanda edit your question and add that code to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to solve the problem. It doesn't hardcode any of the child node names (`TI`, `MO`, `AU`, etc.) so you could potentially use it on similar documents. I've put comments in the code so please read them and ask if you don't understand what the code is doing.

```
$txt = 'your XML string goes here';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($txt);

$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

# find all the nodes types that appear under Record
$cnode_type = array();
foreach ($xp->query("/Results/Recordset/Record/*") as $c) {
    $cnode_type[] = $c->nodeName;
}
# cnode_type now contains the different child node types
$cnode_type = array_unique($cnode_type);

# get all the Record nodes
$recs = $xp->query("/Results/Recordset/Record");

# for every Record node...
foreach ($recs as $par) {
    # for each type of child node...
    foreach ($cnode_type as $c) {
        # run an XPath query to count the number of children of node type $c
        # if there are more than one, we need to remove the extras
        if ($xp->evaluate("count($c)", $par) > 1) {
            # go through all the $c nodes, saving the value in $node_vals
            # delete the node
            $node_vals = [];
            foreach ($xp->query($c, $par) as $n) {
                # only save the contents of nodes with a value
                if (isset($n->nodeValue) && strlen($n->nodeValue) > 0) {
                    $node_vals[] = $n->nodeValue;
                }
                $par->removeChild($n);
            }
            # create a new $c node and set the value to the list in $node_vals
            # add it to the parent node
            $new_node = $dom->createElement($c, implode("; ", $node_vals));
            $par->appendChild($new_node);
        }
    }
}
# print out the result
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Output from the XML you have posted:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Results>
  <Recordset setCount="3">
    <Record setEntry="0">
      <TI>Test-1</TI>
      <MO>Mo-1</MO>
      <JF>OK</JF>
      <JT/>
      <AU>One; Two; three</AU>
    </Record>
    <Record setEntry="1">
      <TI>Test-2</TI>
      <MO>Mo-2</MO>
      <JF/>
      <JT/>
      <AU>One; Two; Three; Four; Five; Six; Seven</AU>
    </Record>
    <Record setEntry="2">
      <TI>Test31</TI>
      <MO>Mo-3</MO>
      <JF/>
      <JT/>
      <AU>One</AU>
    </Record>
  </Recordset>
</Results>
```

Comment: Hi Alien, Thanks a lot. 
1. How can I use a URL of a XML feed replacing the XML string?
2. How to rename XML tags in the same php? Ex: All tags have "abc:" at the beginning (ex: abc:AU). I need to remove "abc:" fromm all the places.

Please again.

Comment: You can use [`$dom->load`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) to get XML from a file/other source. For this question and the previous one you've asked, please click the tick by the answer to show that the problem has been solved. Please start a new question about the tag renaming as it is a different issue.

Comment: @i alarmed alien
Please see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26547050/xml-tag-renaming-in-php)

Comment: @Sanda Will check it out. Please accept the answers (click on the tick symbol) to your other questions--you'll get some extra reputation points and it will mark the questions as completed.

Comment: @i alarmed alien. this code **$node_vals = [];** (# delete the node) gives an error. Can you find why is that and how to overcome please.